# Is this a stag beetle?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: Large Beetle]Just saw this beetle on my window.
The coin is an American dime.
Location is Shenandoah Valley, 
in central Virginia, U.S.A.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a Stag Beetle (Family **Lucanidae**); in particular a member of the genus *Lucanus*.  Looking at the bugguide.net page for the genus [here](http://bugguide.net/node/view/3104/bgpage) your specimen is most likely *Lucanus capreolus*, though *Lucanus placidus* also looks possible -- the two species are very close in appearance, though the former does seem more likely based on distribution.  Consulting The Generic Guide to New World Scarab Beetles [here](http://www.museum.unl.edu/research/entomology/Guide/Scarabaeoidea/Lucanidae/LUC/LUCA/LUC-Key/LucanusK.html) confirms that *L. capreolus* is featured here -- the femora (the first long segment in the leg, and the first we can see -- look at the right front leg) are bicolored (darker at the tips) -- the femora of *L. placidus* would be solid dark brown to black.